# how to update data from child to parent using hooks at login from database

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks

Hi I have just started using hooks and I'm trying to pass data I got from my login page to the parent so the user can access his/her pages, but I don't know how to do that I used this guide [here](https://dev.to/pnkfluffy/passing-data-from-child-to-parent-with-react-hooks-1ji3)

But this just gave me a is not a function error

and I have no idea why

here is my app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import {authenticationService} from '../services/authentication.service';
import Home from '../Pages/Desktop/Desktop';
import Login from '../Pages/Login_Register/Login';
import Register from '../Pages/Login_Register/Register';
import history from '../history';

const App = (props) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(null);
  const [isVIP1, setIsVIP1] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [id, setId] = useState('');
 

useEffect(() => {
  authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(z => {
    setCurrentUser(z) 
    
  });
}, [])

    return (
      <div history={history}>
          <Router>
                  <div>
                    <Switch>
                      <Route path="/register">
                        <Register />
                      </Route>
                      <Route path="/login">
                        <Login firstName={fornavn => setName(fornavn)} user_id={id => setId(id)} admin={admin => setIsAdmin(admin)} vip={vip1 => setIsVIP1(vip1)} />
                      </Route>
                      <Route path="/home">
                        <Home />
                      </Route>
                    </Switch>
                  </div>
          </Router>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {authenticationService} from '../../services/authentication.service';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function Login({firstname, user_id, admin, vip, props}) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(null);
    const [isVIP1, setIsVIP1] = useState(false);
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);
    const [id, setId] = useState('')
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
    if (submitted) {
        return <Redirect push to={{
          pathname: '/home'
        }}
        />
      }   
    let updname = null;
    const onSubmit=(data) => {
                  authenticationService.login(data)
                    .then(
                      user => {
                        setSubmitted(true)
                        updname = user.fornavn;
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    );
                    setName(updname)
                    firstname(updname)
    }
  
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>log ind</h2>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <input name="email" type="text" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                           <input name="password" type="password" ref={register({required: true})} />
                            </div>
                                                        
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit"/>logind</button>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the easiest solution so for but unfortunately it doesn't work anyone that can tell me why or help me find another way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the entire thing started with that I got an error saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'fornavn' of null

This made no sense to me because when I console.log the whole thing fornavn (fistname in danish) was there

```
 useEffect(() => {
  authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(z => {
    console.log(z)
    setCurrentUser(z);
    setName(z.fornavn)
    
  });
 
}, [])
```

so I tried to get the response from the login function witch gave me even more problems the solution to my problem was however to set an if statement in the useEffect like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(z => {
    if(z === null){
      setCurrentUser(null);
      setName(null);
    }else{
      setCurrentUser(z);
      setName(z.fornavn);
    }
   
  });
 
}, [currentUser])
```

And now it works..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the prop defined as firstName in the parent component, and firstname in the child component? If that's accurate, it would cause an error.

As a side note, the way you name your functions does not make it very obvious that they are in fact functions. I would name the function firstname something like handleUpdateFirstName or onChangeFirstName for example. Or...better yet, just pass setName as a prop. You are essentially just redefining it here:

```
firstName={fornavn => setName(fornavn)}
```

I would look into using Proptypes for your components - it will tell you if you have a missing or mislabeled prop.

Edit: example of passing setState as a prop:

```
const Child = ({name, setName}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Edit Name</h1>
    <input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}/>
  </div>
)

const Parent = () => {
  const [ name, setName ] = useState('')
  return (
    <Child name={name} setName={setName}/>
  )
  
}
```

Comment: how do I pass setName as a prop??

Comment: Updating my answer with an example, but the same way you would pass any prop. setState is just a javascript function like any other.

Comment: Okay that is good but it's not the input from the form I want it is the data from the json response that I get from my server